# datagridview filtering function, it works perfect but 3 is also 13 and 334

Tags: vb.net, search, dynamic

so here is my function..it works perfect except it filters every cell the contain the number 3 like 300 313 30 43 but i want it to filter only cell values that have only the single digit 3!!

```
Private Sub LinkLabel4_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LinkLabel4.Click

    Dim search As String
    search = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE rank LIKE '%" & 3 & "%'"

    Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\db.mdb"
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(search, connectionString)

    Dim dt As New DataTable("products")
    adapter.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

another things is the what would be the select statements for filtering with values between 2 specified numbers, like between 4 and 16
Thanks

Comment: But the `rank` field is numeric or string/text type? From your query it seems string/text and this is probably a design problem than a coding problem (as you can see from the results you get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `rank` is a numeric datatype then your query should be as this

```
search = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE rank = 3"
```

and in the second case

```
search = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE rank >=4 AND rank <= 16"
```

To render your search parametrized you could write a method like this

```
Sub RankFilter(ByVal rankLowValue As Integer, Optional ByVal rankHiValue As Integer = -1)

    Dim search As String 
    if rankHiValue = -1 then
        search = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE rank = ?" 
    else
        search = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE rank >= ? and rank <= ?" 

    Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\db.mdb" 

    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(search, connectionString)
    adapters.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rankLo", rankLowValue)
    if rankHiValue <> -1 then
         adapters.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rankHi", rankHiValue)
    end if

    Dim dt As New DataTable("products") 
    adapter.Fill(dt) 
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt 
end sub
```